# Can I take xbox one in carry on luggage on Emirates

Tags: usa, india, hand-luggage, emirates

Am traveling from USA to India on Emirates. Can I take an Xbox one with me as carry on luggage? Please let me know.

Comment: Are you asking about the legality from the point of view of air-travel, or about importing the console and customs?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44005/packing-sensitive-electronics-for-flight

Comment: From the point of view of air travel...

Comment: i took my PS4 with all the cables in my carry-on with my laptop too, as i was afraid they might break it while tossing my luggage around

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, as long as it fits in your carry-on bag - and you are not over the limit in terms of size/weight of your carry-on luggage.

Comment: Thank u so much... So I can carry Xbox and Kinect in my hand luggage in fly Emirates...

Comment: Yup, you only have to remove it for the x-ray scan and place it in its own plastic bin.

Comment: one more question, my flight connections r like Detroit to Boston (USA) then Boston to Dubai and Dubai to chennai... I hope nowhere I will get in to trouble, am I right sir?

Comment: You should have no issues, as long as you are not over your carry-on limit.